# Redirecting amazon ec2 nodejs instance to HTTPS

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, https, certbot

I'm running a node/express app on an amazon ec2 instance, no load-balancer, free tier. I'm trying to redirect everything to HTTPS. Everything I've done up until now was through the EB CLI (eb deploy, eb ssh, and so on).

I got a free certificate from letsencrypt (certbot) and I've set up the nginx.conf as explained in this [tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/e7gzbq/https-with-certbot-for-nginx-on-amazon-linux). I'm able to access both the http and the https versions of the app URL. The http retrieves my nodejs app, but the https returns the default nginx html page (from /usr/share/nginx/html).

I would like to get my nodejs app on HTTPS only and redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS.

My nginx.conf is as follows:

```
# Elastic Beanstalk managed configuration file
# Some configuration of nginx can be by placing files in /etc/nginx/conf.d
# using Configuration Files.
# http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html
#
# Modifications of nginx.conf can be performed using container_commands to modify the staged version
# located in /tmp/deployment/config/etc#nginx#nginx.conf

# Elastic_Beanstalk
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    port_in_redirect off;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
# Elastic Beanstalk Modification(EB_INCLUDE)

    log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                       '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                       '$http_x_forwarded_for';
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
      # Redirect any http requests to https
      if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
         rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
      }
    }
  }

    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem";
        # It is *strongly* recommended to generate unique DH parameters
        # Generate them with: openssl dhparam -out /etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem 2048
        #ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }


include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
# End Modification

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To re-route ports, you can add iptables routing in your EC2 instance, for example:

> sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 443

* Make sure that in EC2 Security Group, the inbound HTTP port 80 source = "Anywhere".

To view the iptables routing entries, run:

> sudo iptables -t nat -L

If you need to remove routing entry (first line), run:

> sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 1